# My 52”brockton ceiling fan will turn on then right off and there is nothing wrong with any of the wiring ive checked it 4 times

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

Ok this is an actual question since i cant post on electrical questions on my 52" brockton ceiling fan turns on for an second or two then turns right off and i checked all the wiring and there is nothing wrong with the wiring

Comment: does it have remote

Comment: Have you checked the fan motor

Comment: Yes it does have an remote

Comment: Possible interference signal, change the dip switches on fan and remote to match each other, also check the battery on the remote

Comment: @crip659 how do you check the fan motor

Comment: @Ruskes   Usually above my pay grade but there are ways to check for shorts, bad bearings, loose connections.

Comment: @crip659 wait just a moment, you get paid here ?

Comment: according to you, you checked the wiring, did you tug on the wires ?

Comment: What does "checked all the wiring" actually mean? There are a variety of checks one can perform, it would be good to know which ones you performed. Also, your lead in, "... this is an actual question..." confuses me, are you referring to some other question you attempted to ask? Something else?